# rewrite tex.web in C++?

Tags: tex-core, web

A few weeks ago I read [this](http://vallettaventures.com/post/13124883568/the-price-of-a-messy-codebase-no-latex-for-the-ipad)
(now [here](https://www.texpad.com/blog/price-of-amessy-latex-not-for-ipad)) article about some difficultites bring TeX to the iPad.

It made me wonder: why not **rewrite** [`TeX.web`](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web) in C++11?  The codebase itself is now quite stable, and (unfortunately) it won't be too many more years before it's completely frozen.

I just [downloaded](http://tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Build/source/texk/web2c/tex.web) the source; it's about 25,000 lines of WEB code.  Let's say the code/comment ratio is 1/5, which results in around 5,000 lines of actual source code.  At one line/minute hand rewrite, that's a little over two weeks.  Even if these calculations are off a bit, it still seems like a "summer vacation" project.

Yes, I know there is a lot more than just `TeX.web`.  But it seems like a native C++ implementation (rather than a `web2c` compiliation) could be an interesting step in a different direction.

Comment: I'll spend you a sixpack of bear if you finished it, I'm a generous person, in one year!

Comment: I'm not really sure this is a question, as such (I find it hard to believe that there will be an answer other than 'well, no one has done it'). The other thing to point out is that LuaTeX has been converted to C, although there are I think GPL pieces to this code which would be an issue for the iPad.

Comment: Also, the linked article has come up before and conflates TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: This cannot be a direct translation, so line for line rewriting simply makes no sense. You *could* translate it line by line, but then you'd lose any benefit of using an object oriented language like C++. You'd have to rethink the structure of TeX.web to make it suited to C++ and that's got to be a huge task.

Comment: My feeling is that the article you refer to has little idea how the TeX world today works.

Comment: Interesting idea, and I'll throw in a bottle of aquavit to go with Herbert's beer (but only if you eat lutefisk while coding).  However, I don't actually see a question here (and I agree with Joseph and Yan's comments in particular) so I'm voting to close as "Not a real question".

Comment: just remember, you'd have to call it something else than just "TeX".  and if you want it to be accepted as a TeX "clone", it would have to pass the trip test.

Comment: Only if you allow me to use SVG images with TeX.

Comment: @Canageek You already can ... via TikZ

Comment: @Dan: Given that LuaTeX is in C anyway, it would seem that group already has access.

Comment: @AndrewStacey 1) That would be useful 2) TikZ scares me. How much work would that be, and where would I go to look up how to do that, given that I've never tried to grok TikZ before?

Comment: More useful than that would be to have a TeX C++ library; that is to easily produce documents from C++ code. I have to yet find something like this.

Comment: TeX.web *has* been rewritten in C++, and in “a little over two weeks”: see https://github.com/nadder/rstex

Comment: We must go further than just translating one language to another. The advantage of rewriting TeX would be in rethinking its design in data-driven way. There are two reasons: (a) we can make it 10 times faster; (b) the current design is impossible to understand.  TeX is all about list manipulations. Lists is antithesis for performance. Nowadays we can do much better than this. Finally, the code itself is a horrible example of imperative programming. Goto, global variables, it is by no means obvious where certain information is produced, where it is changed, and where it is consumed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check Taco's [CXTeX](http://metatex.org/cxtex/); "*A hand-converted C version of TeX*". I think one can throw some C++ syntactic sugar on top of it, but IMO that is as far as you can go without rethinking the whole TeX structure.

Comment: Now I've actually read the article, I fail to see how its conclusion solves any of the mentioned problems; you can have only one executable (TeX), a tiny distribution (LaTeX core, no fonts) and I bet it would take a competent person few hours to build it and the result would be few megabits, without re-writing one line of TeX code.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the source code for LuaTeX: It contains no Pascal code anymore. All of it has been converted by hand to C.